# what is the easiest way to paint train railway?

Tags: texturing, materials, texture-painting

I've build this railway:
[image: railroad tracks]

I want to paint it this way:

1. to paint the wood which cut the railway brown.
2. and the rest of railway with gray color.

How could I do that?
If I add a material it will paint all the railway the same color.

Comment: Use 2 materials, one for the wood part, another - for the steel one

Comment: @MrZak thank you for your reply. but the problem that each time I should select all the woods. and again select the steel. it's hard work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have modeled the railway with athe combo of array+curve modifiers

[image]

I would suggest to assign materials before applying modifiers:

[image]

If you have already applied modifiers and you have a similar topology, you can select linked by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> while at least one face of each metal binaries is selected.

[image][image]

than assing those faces your metal material.

If you have non-linear topology, you'll have to try to mask selection using a combination of selection tools depending on your own topology:

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate the whole track assembly to make an identical copy; Move it up [say GZ5 or more, merely to give you working access to both objects]; Delete all the sleepers from one model and delete the steel tracks from the other copy; give each model the necessary materials; GZ-5 [to restore the copy back down to its original position and use "join" on the l/h tools menu to join tracks to sleepers but maintain differing materials - just a thought!